# Error creating two Redis To Go clients in NodeJS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, redistogo

I've got a single web dyno running on a Heroku app that's built using NodeJS and it's using a single Redis To Go database on the Nano (free) tier. That tier is supposed to support up to ten connections, yet if I try to connect to it in two different modules using:

```
var redis_url = require('url').parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
var redis = require('redis').createClient(redis_url.port, redis_url.hostname);
```

I get this error when trying to start the app:

> Error: Ready check failed: NOAUTH Authentication required. Mar 31
>   21:52:18 <> app/web.1:     at RedisClient.on_info_cmd
>   (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:380:35)

The `REDISTOGO_URL` environment variable is set correctly, and if I remove the code from one of the modules then it starts fine with no errors. I could create one client and pass it to each module, but I'd really prefer to understand what's actually causing the problem here.

Can somebody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the exact issue you describe but i was able to get around the auth issue by doing the following

```
var redis_url = require('url').parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL)
var redisClient1 = require('redis').createClient(redis_url.port, redis_url.hostname, {auth_pass: redis_url.auth.split(":")[1]});
redisClient1.on("ready", function(){
  console.log("one ready")
})

var redisClient2 = require('redis').createClient(redis_url.port, redis_url.hostname, {auth_pass: redis_url.auth.split(":")[1]});
redisClient2.on("ready", function(){
  console.log("two ready")
})
```

Does the above work for you?

Comment: Wow, I'm such an idiot. In the first module I had code to do the auth `if(url.auth)
{
 redis.auth(url.auth.split(':')[1]);
}`

.. which I failed to put in the other one! Still, a better error message would have helped.